# Is SimplePHPBlog a secure blogging engine?

Tags: security, blog

Has anyone used the blog engine SimplePHPBlog? It is a simple blog engine that uses only text files (no database).

My problem with it is that the content directory where the texts files are stored appears to require being world writeable/readable (i.e. permission 777) for it to work. This means anyone can access the text files with a browser! These text files include the blog/comment poster's IP and email address!

This is not secure or good practice, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those files in the web root? Or below it? If they are below it you're fine. If not you can always block those files from being viewed in a browser using .htaccess. Just place the .htaccess file in that directory with code similar to this:

```
<Files *.db>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
</Files>
```

Change `.db` to be whatever file extension those files are using. Then whenever someone tries to access them via a browser they will get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: The files are at example.com/content/...

Comment: I tried the .htaccess file in the content directory (replacing *.db with *.txt) but the files are still accessible.

Comment: If the whole /content/ directory is private, you can remove the `<Files *.db>` bit and make the whole directory inaccessible.

Comment: The answer is probably a variation of this using .htaccess. Although I note I said it didn't work as intended at the time I can't test it any more so I am marking this as the answer. In my opinion the method chosen by SimplePHPBlog is obviously not very _private_ if contributors' IP addresses and every post are visible to the world but this doesn't really seem to expose any other _security_ vulnerabilities.